# Google Script using an API cURL Request and getting a 422 Response code

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, post, http-status-code-422

My coding knowledge is pretty shaky because I didn't learn it orderly.
Right now, I am trying to send an cURL Request and the documentation is:

curl https://api.at356.com/studio/v1/sd-large/complete 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY' 
-X POST 
-d '{"prompt": "Life is like",
"numResults": 1,
}'

this is the code

```js
function searchFor(query) {
  // Base URL to access 
  var urlTemplate = "https://api.at356.com/studio/v1/sd-large/complete "
  // Script-specific credentials & search engine
  var ApiKey = "shwMCMgEviwfz6X7Rvbtna6";

  var prompt = {
    "prompt": query,
    "numResults": 1,
  }
  // Build custom cURL  
  var cURL = {
      'method': 'POST',
      "headers":{
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": ApiKey,
      },
      
      prompt,
      
   
    
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "followRedirects": true,
        "validateHttpsCertificates": true
  };

  // Perform Request
  //Logger.log( UrlFetchApp.getRequest(urlTemplate, params) );  // Log query to be sent
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlTemplate, cURL,);
  var respCode = response.getResponseCode();

  if (respCode !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Error " + respCode + " " + response.getContentText());
  } else {
    // Successful search, log & return results
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log("Obtained %s search results in %s seconds.",
      result.searchInformation.formattedTotalResults,
      result.searchInformation.formattedSearchTime);


    return result;
  }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl https://api.at356.com/studio/v1/sd-large/complete \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY' \
    -X POST \
    -d '{"prompt": "Life is like", "numResults": 1, }'
  ```
- You have already confirmed that your this curl command works fine.

#### Modified script:

```js
var query = "###"; // Please set the value.
var ApiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.

var url = "https://api.at356.com/studio/v1/sd-large/complete";
var prompt = {
  "prompt": query,
  "numResults": 1,
};
var params = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ApiKey },
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(prompt),
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
console.log(response.getContentText());
```

#### Note:

- From your sample curl command, `Authorization` is like `-H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY'`. So I modified to `"headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ApiKey }`. If your actual API key is like `Bearer ###`, please modify this to `"headers": { "Authorization": ApiKey }`.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Success. Thank you so much